# unable to handle the leaked connection count of the data source in web logic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, datasource

I created a data source to access the database in one of my projects, but the problem is even though I am trying to close every connection that has been made

```
connect.close();
```

number of leaked connection counts are increasing unexpectedly. What should I do that to encounter this. I am using Weblogic 11G as app server, Oracle 11G and Eclipse IDE.

Comment: you need to show your jdbc code. You are using `connect.close()` doesn't mean that you are hitting that line of code. You code might be getting stuck somewhere before that.

Comment: @SabirKhan I am sure that the code `connect .close()` is being executed, the code is too lengthy to share.

Comment: As per my experience, that is usually the reason if programmer has even coded `close()` at appropriate places.

Answer (score 1):

You should activate the InactiveConnectionTimeoutSeconds parameter on your datasource. It is disabled by default (0). It will enable WebLogic to retrieve unclosed connections from applications after several seconds. It will also log a stack trace in the server's log that will be useful to see where the code is leaking.